# What's the standard way for server to server integration (cross internet) authentication

Tags: authentication

Let's say I have two servers in different data centers. They need to talk to each other, how to protect the security? TLS is a must. For authentication, we are concerning to use credential since if it get stolen anyone can use it to do the integration call. Then we start to think about to use Mutual authentication based on client certificate. However, my understanding is client certificate can also get stolen. Then is it really much stronger than username/password? 
In addition, if we do IP restriction, will it make the integration much safer?

Looking forward to your advice.

Thanks!

Comment: If you worry about credential stealing (which often means your system is compromised) you can use HSM/TPM to store the certificates. Besides using TLS client authentication SSH client carts are also common. For a larger number of loudly associated endpoints the less secure TLS Server authentication with BasicAuth or ContentEncryption (AS2/CMS, PGP, XML DSig/AS4) is used. Client certificates avoid the need of password policy and brute force protection)

Answer (score 1):

[ssh](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/) includes by default peer server authentication: each server has its own private key that only lies in a root only readable folder, and all collaborating machines have the list of their peers public keys.

A common configuration then allows ssh to pass the calling user name, and the callee does trust that user name because it has been authenticated on a trusted  peer. This normally does not extend to the root account but is commonly used for unattended remote servers collaboration with dedicated accounts.

Answer (score 1):

TLS mutual authentication is your most secure option and is what I generally recommend for server to server authentication, except for one very specific, less common situation which I'll explain later. TLS mutual certificate authentication is more secure than password authentication because with TLS certificate authentication, the private keys are never sent in the communication. With a pre-shared key authentication (a.k.a. password) the secret token can be compromised just by one successful interception, and since both sides of the server necessarily handle the secret token at one point or another, so you can compromise both authenticators by just compromising one side of the connection. Certificate authentication limits the impact as only one side of the credential is compromised.

With mutual server to server TLS authentication, you have the option of using a public CA, which costs a small amount of money but allows you to outsource the complexity of running a root certification authority to someone with a proper experience to do so, or you can run a private root, so you don't have to trust a third party with the security of your network of systems. There are pros and cons of each, and you should consider them carefully.

> However, my understanding is client certificate can also get stolen.

Any credentials can be stolen, that's why you must secure your servers and make contingency plans for these situations. If you have a situation where you're concerned about theft of private key, you have two options:

1. In most cases, you can design processes and procedures so you can quickly revoke and replace the stolen certificate. This may mean that you should use a root certificate that generates the peer certificates, and/or you need a way to relatively quickly revoke and deploy new roots to all servers that need to authenticate each other.
2. If you have a situation where it's extremely difficult to replace the root of trust, for example if you have millions of machines managed by hundreds or thousands of different companies/individual, then you want to really secure the root of trust. In this case, you should do #1, and also use a hardware security module. An HSM is a hardware token that stores your private key and do cryptographic operations so that the key never leaves the HSM. HSM allows you to convert the risk of securing the server to physical security of physical theft of the HSM itself.

---

My other recommendation may be needed if you have a situation where you need end to end authentication, where your security model is such that the servers is not considered a trusted party in the communication between users of either servers. The most common example of this is end to end encrypted email and chat. In this case, you want to add an application-level authentication and encryption, such that the servers never have the user's private key and cannot therefore impersonate their users. In this security model, users trust other users directly, but not necessarily trust the server except as a simple delivery agent. My recommendation for this is to use GPG or anything that implements Double Ratchet such as the Signal protocol.

As an alternative, OAuth/OAuth2 may be necessary when you need a three legged authentication: user/application, identity server, and resource server. Unless you actually have a three legged situation, you probably don't really need the complexity of OAuth/OAuth2.

---

> In addition, if we do IP restriction, will it make the integration much safer?

If you already have proper authentication, it will make the integration marginally safer, but not much. IP restriction is really only useful against DoS attacks because IP firewall is relatively cheap to enforce with a layer 3 firewall, but by itself, it is not sufficient for any sort of authentication and not having IP restriction is usually not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

When the list of interconnected systems is small and is relatively static, IP Address whitelisting is the most commonly used mechanism. It is less secure than using two-way TLS authentication.

To worry about "what if my TLS cert is stolen?" is like worrying about "what if my brakes fail?". For this reason, it doesn't make sense to do away with the brakes. Rather, you augment that good solution with periodic inspections and replacement.

In your case, the solution would be to

- make sure the servers are secured properly to minimize the possibility of compromise
- put in place a quick detection and rapid response process to recover in case of a compromise.

That apart -

The most common form of **server-to-server authentication on top of TLS** is at the application level. In a way we can call it as application to application authentication.

OAUTH/OAUTH2 are designed just for this purpose. You might want to consider using one of them.

Comment: Last I checked, a single brake manufacturer slipping up or going rogue won't retroactively cause all brakes around the world to fail. Analogy assuming a client certificate signed by a client CA (e.g. signed Windows executables).

Comment: IP address white listing is not a form of authentication, except over a properly configured, trusted network. Since in this question the machines need to authenticate over untrusted network (i.e. the public internet), then IP address cannot and shouldn't be used to authenticate anything.